# register child class in another plugin

Tags: plugins, widgets, oop

I think this should be relatively easy, but somehow I cannot figure out how to do this.
essentially there's a preexisting plugin that does this:

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("Foo");'));
if ( ! class_exists( 'Foo' ) ) {
class Foo extends WP_Widget {
        /*constructs etc*/
}}
```

now i would like to write another plugin (extension essentially), that extends the above. I tried to do something like the following (and also tried - in vain - to find some examples/documentation )

```
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("Bar");'));
class Bar extends Foo {     
    function __construct() {
        /*do stuff*/
    }
}
```

but all i ever get is

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Foo' not found in ...
```

so I suppose it's a question of making 'Bar' execute AFTER Foo, but I dunno how.

any hints/ideas/snippets or even just links to docs etc would be much appreciated as I am failing at the first hurdle here..:(

Answer (score 1):

I question the wisdom of extending a class from another plugin. You have no idea what will happen next time that other plugin gets updated.

However, generally speaking you can control when in a hook "queue" a function runs by [passing a third parameter-- a priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). So pass a priority high enough and your function should run after the other plugin's function.

```
add_action(
  'widgets_init', 
  create_function('', 'register_widget("Bar");')
  ,100
);
```

I don't know if that will work in your case. I've never tried it.

You should also be aware that you could have trouble because of plugin load order.

[Changing Plugin Load Order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/changing-plugin-load-order)
[Does an activated plugin automatically mean its methods are available to other WP functions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/does-an-activated-plugin-automatically-mean-its-methods-are-available-to-other-w/16941#16941)

[`widget_init` runs after `plugins_loaded`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) so that probably won't be an issue in you case.

On further investigation... I get errors involving missing variables required by the constructor. The following works.

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Foo' ) ) {
  class Foo extends WP_Widget {
      /*constructs etc*/
      function __construct($id = 'twidg', $descr = 'Test Widget', $opts = array()) {
    $widget_opts = array();
    parent::__construct($id,$descr,$widget_opts);
      /*do stuff*/
      }
  }
}
function rw_cb() {
register_widget("Foo");
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'rw_cb');

class Bar extends Foo {     
    function __construct() {
      $widget_opts = array();
      parent::__construct('twidgextended','Test Widget 2',$widget_opts);
    }
}
function rw_cb_2() {
  register_widget("Bar");
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'rw_cb_2');
```

When each component is pasted into a dummy plugin file, it works. The only time I get a fatal error involving a class file not found is if I try to activate the plugin with the `Bar` class definition, before the plugin with the `Foo` definition, which makes sense.

Wrapping that block as follows solves that issue though and you can activate in any order.

```
if (class_exists('Foo')) {
  class Bar extends Foo {     
      function __construct() {
    $widget_opts = array();
    parent::__construct('twidgextended','Test Widget 2',$widget_opts);
      }
  }

  function rw_cb_2() {
    register_widget("Bar");
  }
  add_action('widgets_init', 'rw_cb_2');
}
```

Comment: oh, and regarding:
>I question the wisdom of extending a class from another plugin. You have no idea what will happen next time that other plugin gets updated.

i actually do , as the "other one"(FOO) is mine, but I'm trying to - independently so to speak - extend it

Comment: If both plugins are yours, it makes more sense. You didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: i know, sorry ...

Comment: anyway, it doesn't matter what I set the priority to unfortunately , I'll always get the same fatal error. I'll have a read through the docs/links you posted. maybe I'll find something there..thanks though

Comment: your edit / other solution looks a lot more elegant than what I was able to come up with below . I'll give that a go too. thanks for taking the time . much appreciated

Comment: Hi again,
it appears your solution seem to work only when it's in the same plugin :( not when it's on another one (as outlined above, the idea was to make the extension/2nd plugin - BAR - dependent on the first "FOO" but being able to (de)-activate it at will (does that make sense ?!)

Comment: I don't know what you are doing but that works from two different plugins when I tested it, exactly as I explained in the answer.

Comment: ok, i shall try again. I must have screwed something up I guess

Comment: If it still doesn't work I probably can't help without seeing the complete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

ah, but you did point me in the right direction (specifically your second link). the following (as it stands in my scenario at least ) seems to do the trick. thank you.

```
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'extend_foo' );
function extend_foo(){
    if (class_exists( 'Foo' ) ) {
        class Bar extends Foo {
            function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();          
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

(although I'm not sure if  this is the most elegant way of doing things though...but if it works....)

Comment: edited my own answer as it appears I could make it a lot more concise..