# how to extend a WP_widget twice

Tags: widgets, customization

Has someone ever tried to extend calss WP_Widget, then extend it again ?

Having to related widgets, I tried to create the first extending WP_Widget, :

```
class FirstWidget  extends WP_Widget {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(
```

etc

and then extending the First to create the second one :

```
class SecondWidget  extends FirstWidget  {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(
```

this works well, except that the second widget isn't available in the drag and drop widgets area. I can explicitly use it in my code :

```
the_widget('SecondWidget', array('title'=> "New title")
```

and it shows well, but I can't drag'n'drop it.

Someone knows why ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that all of your parameters are passed all the way through to the `WP_Widget` class. Your code is very truncated but I am pretty sure that is what you are doing wrong.

The widget code below works-- it doesn't do much of anything, but it works. See if you can use it as a template to sort out your own code.

```
  class Foo extends WP_Widget {
    /*constructs etc*/
    function __construct($id = 'twidg', $descr = 'Test Widget', $opts = array()) {
      $widget_opts = array();
      parent::__construct($id,$descr,$widget_opts);
      /*do stuff*/
    }

    function widget() {
      echo 'test widget';
    }
  }

function rw_cb() {
  register_widget("Foo");
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'rw_cb');

class Bar extends Foo {     
    function __construct() {
      $widget_opts = array();
      parent::__construct('twidgextended','Test Widget 2',$widget_opts);
    }

    function widget() {
      echo 'test widget 2';
    }
}
function rw_cb_2() {
  register_widget("Bar");
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'rw_cb_2');
```

The code [is mostly cribbed from another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100721/21376). I made minor changes before posting it here.