# How to export and import plugin data through WordPress tools option

Tags: plugins, import, export

I have a plugin which doesn't have import/export option in WordPress tools
http://wordpress.org/plugins/color-manager/

How can I add this functionality?

Comment: I wrote this [plugin](https://github.com/rrikesh/WordPress-Export-Options) that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad, but **EVERYTHING IS POSSIBLE**. I never tried this, but I can bet it's possible.

You have to gather some knowledge and walk trough the right way:

- Know about **WP Hooks** - [Intro](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-use-wordpress-hooks/)
- Find the [**Hooks Database** by Adam Brown](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks)
- Let's learn the way of the modifications from **[HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30405/how-to-edit-a-wordpress-plugin-without-break-its-update-process)**

And then start tweaking as per your wish.

- [This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106289/import-export-plugin-settings-for-wordpress) can assist you.
- [This one](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-easily-import-or-export-any-of-your-wordpress-database-content-using-phpmyadmin-3415) may also help you in the process of designing your thing

But the motto is: **EVERYTHING IS POSSIBLE**.