# wp_mail is undefined

Tags: plugin-development, wp-mail

I am writing a plugin that opens up a form to invite people to a website by email and want to use `wp_mail()`.

Whenever I use the `wp_mail()` function in any file in my plugin folder I always end up with:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_mail()

The code segment in question is:

```
function send_email() {
    $subject = 'test';
    $message = 'this is a test from send invitation';
    $to = 'navanitachora@gmail.com';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

I am at my wits end as to why this should be happening when so many plugins use `wp_mail()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may call the function too early. You have to wait until the action `'plugins_loaded'` fires.

`wp_mail()` is defined in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`.
`pluggable.php` is loaded in `wp-settings.php` *after* the plugins are loaded but *before* `'plugins_loaded'` is called.

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16941/73) for an example.

Comment: How would I call the function after plugins_loaded fires and still make it send the email when required?

Comment: Just do _everything_ after `'plugins_loaded'`. Then you don’t have to worry about the availability of pluggable functions.

Comment: Thank you @toscho for your reply I added the `add_action` method with `"plugins_loaded"` and wp_mail sends out the email but it sends it out everytime the page loads is there a way to have wp_mail defined but not send out the email unless I press submit on my form. There is something simple I am missing here but I do not exactly know what.

Comment: Take a look at my plugin [Report Broken Video](https://github.com/toscho/Report-Broken-Video) – I check several conditions in it before I send an email.

Comment: Thanks @toscho for pointing me to your Report Broken Video code it has been most helpful and I have modified my own code to use a class namespace. However, I am having a few problems using the class because I am not sure how to actually use or access those methods in my template. Should I instantiate it in my template and then echo out the form code using the appropriate get form code or should this happen automatically. I have been writing OOP code for quite a while but I am not sure how to proceed in the case. Do let me know if I should ask this as a new question.

Comment: @navanitachora There are two ways: 1. Add a static method to allow access to the last class instance, or 2. define an action. But you are right: This would be a good new question. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have posted a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44708/using-a-plugin-class-inside-a-template