# Using a plugin class inside a template

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I am writing a plugin to send an invitation to a friend which opens up a form when a link is clicked. I encapsulated all the functions in class by following the code given in the Report Broken Video plugin by @toscho. The relevant code is below:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Send Invitation
Plugin URI: http://w3boutique.net
Description: Emails a the link of the current page to a friend
Author: Nandakumar Chandrasekhar
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://w3boutique.net/about-nanda.html
License: GPL2
*/

// include() or require() any necessary files here

// Settings and/or Configuration Details go here
define('SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION', '3.1.1');

define('SEND_INVITATION_PLUGIN_URL', plugins_url('', __FILE__));

add_action( 'init', array( 'SendInvitation', 'nc_sendinvitation_init' ) );

class SendInvitation {

    protected $nonce_name = 'nc_sendinvitation';
    protected $post_url = '';

    public static function nc_sendinvitation_init() {
        new self;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'nc_sendinvitation_head' ));
        add_action( 'init', array(&$this,  'nc_sendinvitation_check_wordpress_version' ));
       add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'nc_sendinvitation_form_action' ));
       //$this->post_url = $this->nc_sendinvitation_get_post_url();
   }

   public function nc_sendinvitation_head() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'send_invitation_js',
        plugins_url( 'js/send-invitation.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' ) );

       wp_enqueue_style( 'send_invitation_css',
        plugins_url( 'css/send-invitation.css', __FILE__ ) );
   }

   public function nc_sendinvitation_check_wordpress_version() {
       global $wp_version;

       $exit_msg = 'Send Invitation requires version '
    . SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION
    . 'or newer <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress">Please
update!</a>';

       if ( version_compare( $wp_version, SEND_INVITATION_MIN_WORDPRESS_VERSION, '<') )
       {
            exit( $exit_msg );
       }
   }

   public function nc_sendinvitation_form_action() {

        $action = '';
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' )
        {
             $action = $this->nc_sendinvitation_get_form();
        }
        else if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
            $action = $this->nc_sendinvitation_handle_submit();
        }
        return $action;
   }

   public function nc_sendinvitation_get_form() {
       // Start the output buffer, prevents content being output directly into
       // script, instead it is stored in a buffer which can then be flushed
       // to allow the include file to be stored in a variable
       // See http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=124537
       ob_start();
       include('send-invitation-form.php');
       $send_invitation_link = ob_get_clean();

       return $send_invitation_link;
   }

   public function nc_sendinvitation_handle_submit() {
         if ( isset( $_POST['form_type'] ) && ( $_POST['form_type'] == 'nc_sendinvitation' ) ) {
            $to = 'navanitachora@gamil.com';
            $subject = 'Invitation to SwanLotus';
            $message = 'Navanitachora invites you to take a look at this link';
            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            $result = 'Email was sent successfully';
    }
    else {
        $result = $this->nc_sendinvitation_get_form();
    }
    return $result;
}

public function nc_sendinvitation_get_post_url() {
    global $post;
    $blog_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
    $post_id = '';
    if (is_home($blog_id)) {
        $post_id = $blog_id;
    } else {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    return get_permalink($post_id);
}
}
/* End of File */
?>
```

I am at a loss as to how to use this class in my template so that I can display the form. I know that I need to instantiate the class but I am not sure where to put the code and how to access the object so that I can use it in my template. I have knowledge of OOP but have not used it in this context before and require a little bit of step by step instruction.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to use your class without knowing the object is an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). You register the action before the theme files for presentation are loaded, WordPress will handle the rest.

Sample code:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Plugin Action Demo
 */
add_action( 'init', array ( 'Plugin_Action_Demo', 'init' ) );

class Plugin_Action_Demo
{
    /**
     * Creates a new instance.
     *
     * @wp-hook init
     * @see    __construct()
     * @return void
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        new self;
    }

    /**
     * Register the action. May do more magic things.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'plugin_action_demo', array ( $this, 'print_foo' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Prints 'foo' multiple $times.
     *
     * Usage:
     *    <code>do_action( 'plugin_action_demo', 50 );</code>
     *
     * @wp-hook plugin_action_demo
     * @param int $times
     * @return void
     */
    public function print_foo( $times = 1 )
    {
        print str_repeat( ' foo ', (int) $times );
    }
}
```

Now you can call `do_action( 'plugin_action_demo', 50 );` somewhere in your theme or in another plugin, and you don't have to care about the inner workings of the class anymore.

If you deactivate the plugin you are still safe: WordPress just ignores unknown actions and the `do_action()` will do no harm. Plus, other plugins are able to remove or replace the action, so you have build a nice mini API with one `add_action()`.

You could also build a singleton:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Plugin Singleton Demo
 */
class Plugin_Singleton_Demo
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance if there isn't one.
     *
     * @wp-hook init
     * @return object
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {

        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Not accessible from the outside.
     */
    protected function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Prints 'foo' multiple $times.
     *
     * @param int $times
     * @return void
     */
    public function print_foo( $times = 1 )
    {
        echo str_repeat( ' foo ', (int) $times );
    }
}
```

Now `print_foo()` is accessible per:

```
Plugin_Singleton_Demo::get_instance()->print_foo();
```

I don’t recommend the Singleton pattern. It has some [serious drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of `plugin_action_demo` in `add_action()`? How does `do_action( 'print_foo', 50 );` know that the action is `plugin_action_demo` or is that name irrelevant?

Comment: Ok, was a bit confused. :) Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: For the record: `declare()` requires php 5.3+ :)

Comment: Thanks that works just have to add some validation and I should be done. Thanks @toscho you have taught me a lot. :-)

Comment: @tosco Found your answer looking for articles about singletons for WordPress plugins. You do realize you _are_ using a Singleton in your recommended answer, you are just not enforcing it? Imagine a themer calls `new Plugin_Action_Demo`?? Anyone using `do_action('plugin_action_demo')` would trigger two (2) calls to `Plugin_Action_Demo->print_foo()`, not what you want. The furor over singletons ignores there are appropriate use-cases. As an FYI both @ericmann and I are blogging now to advocate singletons for WordPress plugin namespacing, he at eamann.com and me at hardcorewp.com.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel The approach I am recommending currently is this: https://gist.github.com/3804204 – you can access it like a Singleton, but you don’t have to.

Comment: @tocho Okay, I can see that you don’t have to access your example like a singleton, but what's the point? In what use-cases would you want to?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Unit-tests and child classes. And no, I do not change visibility in a child class unless I am forced to. :)

Comment: @toscho Do you actually unit test classes used for the base of your plugins? If yes how do you deal with the hooks that can't be tested without a page load? Doesn't that make unit testing those classes moot? And I'm subclassing my singletons without a problem, matter of fact it's key to my architecture; how is it an issue? BTW, I'm about to publish a post advocating singletons and will write a follow-up addressing unit-testing. But if you legitimate reasons against I'd like to know before I publish. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I use http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests – page load is not a problem. And I don’t like Eric’s idea to test a subclass that isn’t the actual production code and differs in behavior. I should blog about this, comments are not made for this. :)

Comment: @toscho - Looking forward to your blog post. BTW, I didn't understand what you meant by _"I do not change visibility in a child class unless I am forced to."_

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Constructor visibility as recommended by Eric.

Comment: @toscho Ah, Eric's not me. :)

Comment: @toscho Also, when you said _"page load is not a problem"_ I think you misunderstood; I was saying page load is pretty much the only way to test a class used to wire up hook handlers with methods, i.e. that classic unit testing does not make sense.