# Registering and using actions which return results in a Plugin class

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I have a plugin class which contains a function spektrix_list_events()

```
class SpektrixPlugin {

    public function __construct(){

        add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'init' ));
    }

    public function init()
    {
        add_action( 'spektrix_list_events', array ( $this, 'spektrix_list_events' ));
    }

    public function spektrix_list_events($getPrices = FALSE) {
        $api = new SpektrixApiClient();
        return $api->getAllEvents($getPrices);

    }
}

$SpektrixEvents = new SpektrixPlugin;
add_action('init', array($SpektrixEvents, 'init'));
```

In a template file, I want to be able to call do_action('spektrix_list_events') but can't seem to get this working. I've tried following the advice [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44708/using-a-plugin-class-inside-a-template/44710#44710)

Additional question - is using add_action() the recommended way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

The method is in fact being called but no results are returned. So how should one call a plugin class method which returns some output for display?

Answer (score 2):

Some actions hooks need to be fired on specific events. Try this code:

```
class SpektrixPlugin {

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
    }

    public function spektrix_list_events($getPrices = FALSE) {
        $api = new SpektrixApiClient();
        return $api->getAllEvents($getPrices);
    }

    public function init(){
        add_action( 'spektrix_list_events', array ( $this, 'spektrix_list_events' ));
    }

 }

 $SpektrixEvents = new SpektrixPlugin();
```

I've tested this code and it works:

```
class SpektrixPlugin {

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
    }

    public function spektrix_list_events() {
        echo 'test';
    }

    public function init(){
        add_action( 'spektrix_list_events', array ( $this, 'spektrix_list_events' ));
    }

 }

 $SpektrixEvents = new SpektrixPlugin();

 //this print 'test', so it works.
 do_action('spektrix_list_events');
```

But .... I've been reading the Wordpress documentation about `do_action()` and it says clearly that `do_action()` will call the function/method but **it won't return anything**. Quoteing Wordpress about `do_action()`:

> This function works similar to apply_filters() with the exception that
>   nothing is returned and only the functions or methods are called.

So, you should check the [apply_filters()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) function which works in a similar way that `do_action()` but can return the value returned by the called method or look for another implementation. `do_action()` is not suitable to return values.

An example usgin apply_filters:

```
class SpektrixPlugin {

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
    }

    public function spektrix_list_events() {
        $myvar = "Hey, I'm works";
        return $myvar;
    }

    public function init(){
        add_filter( 'spektrix_list_events', array ( $this, 'spektrix_list_events' ));
    }

 }

 $SpektrixEvents = new SpektrixPlugin;

 $test = apply_filters('spektrix_list_events','');
 var_dump($test);
```

Anyway, I think that this approach used to get data is no the appropiate. Although `apply_filters()` will work to get a value, as in the above example, the function is specially designed to filter a value, not to get one. I think the best you can do is have a `get` method in your class used to get the value you want, then you can apply filters to that value or do actions with it.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I do do_action('spektrix_list_events') in a template, nothing is returned. The docs seem to bear this out. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action. So whats the best way to call a plugin function if you need to return something? I was previously just using the object directly in the template e.g. $SpektrixPlugin->doMyMethod()

Comment: See my edited answer. It works. So it has to be the call to `$api->getAllEvents($getPrices);` what returns nothing or maybe you need to echo the returning data.

Comment: It does work but only for echoing a value, not returning an array of values. I don't want to echo anything out in my plugin. The data I'm returning is also not wordpress post data but data from a third-party API.

Comment: Please, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

When working with classes and action, is a good practise, give an easy way to remove the action.

Using something like `add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'init' ));` removing this action, can be done, but is [far from easy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088).

Another thing to consider, is that if you plain to *use* a plugin from theme, is a good idea insert some custom filters and actions hooks to customize the behavior of your plugin form themes.

So, in your case you can do something like this

```
add_action('init', 'initSpektrixPlugin');

function initSpektrixPlugin() {
  // if the class isn't in the main plugin file, you can require class file here, e.g.:
  // require_once( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'inc/SpektrixPlugin.class.php' );
  SpektrixPlugin::init();
}
```

After that, the class can be something like this:

```
class SpektrixPlugin {

    protected static $events = array();

    public static function init()
    {
        add_action( 'spektrix_list_events', array ( __CLASS__, 'printEvents' ) );
    }

    protected static function getEvents( $getPrices = false )
    {
        $cached = self::getCachedEvents( $getPrices );
        if ( $cached ) 
           // last 'true' param means we are returning cached result
           return apply_filters('spektrix_events', $cached, $getPrices, true);
        // requiring the api client class from here, you include it
        // only if you don't already have cached results
        require_once( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'SpektrixApiClient.php' );
        $api = new SpektrixApiClient();
        $events = self::setCachedEvents( $api->getAllEvents($getPrices), $getPrices);
        // a custom action to customize behavior from theme
        do_action('spektrix_events_getted', $events, $getPrices);
        // return events after a custom filter, to customize behavior from theme
        // last 'false' param means we are returning not cached result
        return apply_filters('spektrix_events', $events, $getPrices, false);
    }

    protected static function getCachedEvents( $getPrices = false )
    {
      $key = $getPrices ? 1 : 0;
      if ( isset( self::$events[$key] ) ) return self::$events[$key];
      return false;
    }

    protected static function setCachedEvents( $events, $getPrices = false )
    {
      $key = $getPrices ? 1 : 0;
      self::$events[$key] = $events;
      return $events; 
    }

    public static function printEvents( $getPrices = false )
    {
        $events = self::getEvents( $getPrices );

        // debug
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($events);
        echo '</pre><br />';
        // end debug

        // print here your events..
        // I don't know if it's a string, an object, an array...
    }

}
```

And in your template file use just

```
<?php do_action('spektrix_list_events'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php do_action('spektrix_list_events', true); // getPrices = true ?>
```

Code is rough and **untested**, but should give you a direction to start.

Answer (score -1):

If you want any function to work juhst hook it to your appropriate needs.I think in your case you want to execute function `spektrix_list_events()`. It is in class so use array in hooking `add_action('appropriate hook',array('SpektrixPlugin','spektrix_list_events'));`
Hope this will help.

Comment: I was already doing this and the linked question already had this information FYI. The problem seems to be that running do_action('spektrix_list_events') does not return any results.