# Problem with `wp_mail()`

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-mail

I have researched a lot and I can not do this plugin to send mail when it comes in step 2, which displays more options form. In the first stage it correctly sends the name and email to the database, but in step 2, `wp_mail()` doesn't fire.

Main code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Formulario Cotação
Plugin URI: http://solutionsagencia.com.br
Description: Plugin para cotação em 2 passos.
Version: 0.0.1
Author: Wendell Christian
Author URI: http://solutionsagencia.com.br
License: GPLv2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

// Verifica se não existe nenhum classe com o mesmo nome
if ( ! class_exists( 'FormularioCotacao' ) ) {
  class FormularioCotacao {
    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'cotacao', array( $this, 'ExibirTexto' ) );
    }

    public function ExibirTexto () {
        $FormularioCotacaoURL = WP_CONTENT_URL;
        $FormularioCotacaoURL = WP_CONTENT_URL.'/plugins/'.plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/';
        $urlsite = site_url();

        return "<div class='principal-form' id='principal-form'>
        <div class='col-md-35'><div class='titulo-inicie'>INICIE SUA COTAÇÃO AQUI</div></div>
        <form type='post' action='' id='cadastraForm'>
        <div class='col-md-65'><div class='col-md-34'><input type='text' name='nome' id='nome' class='campo-form' placeholder='Nome' maxlength='50'></div>
        <div class='col-md-34-2'><input type='email' name='email' id='email' class='campo-form' placeholder='Email' maxlength='120'/></div>
        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='addCustomer'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='urlsite' id='urlsite' value='".$urlsite."'/>
        <div class='col-md-30'><button type='submit' id='enviarform' class='botao-enviar'><span class='icone-cadastrar'></span>Efetue sua simulação</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id='feedback'></div>
        <div id='passo2form' class='passo2form'></div>
        <div class='col-md-100' id='botao-enviar-2'>
        <div class='col-md-70 margin-bottom-15 margin-top-15'><button type='submit' id='enviarform2' class='botao-enviar'><span class='icone-cadastrar'></span>Efetue sua simulação</button>
        </div></div>";
    }
  }

  /* Carrega a classe */
  $FormularioCotacao_settings = new FormularioCotacao();

} // class_exists

function addCustomer() {
  global $wpdb;

  $nome  = trim( $_POST['nome'] );
  $email = trim( $_POST['email'] );

  if ( $wpdb->insert( 'wp_formclientes',array(
    'nome'  => $nome,
    'email' => $email
  )) === FALSE) {

    echo "Error";
  } else {
    //mensagem de sucesso
  }

  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer' ); // not really needed
add_action( 'init', function() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {      
    $nome      = trim( $_POST['nome'] );
    $email     = trim( $_POST['email'] );
    $comparar  = ( $_POST['comparar'] );  
    $tipo      = ( $_POST['tipo'] );  
    $telefone  = ( $_POST['telefone'] );
    $profissao = ( $_POST['profissao'] );
    $zd        = ($_POST['z-d']); 
    $para      = "wendell@solutionsagencia.com.br";
    $assunto   = "Cotação em Compara Saúde" . $nome;
    $conteudo  =
            "<b>Nome:</b> $nome" .
            "<br><b>Email:</b> $email" .
            "<br><b>Comparar:</b> $comparar" .
            "<br><b>Tipo:</b> $tipo" .
            "<br><b>Telefone:</b> $telefone" .
            "<br><b>Profissão:</b> $profissao" .
            "<br><b>0 a 18:</b> $zd";

     $headers = array(
       'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
       'Reply-To' => $name . '<' . $email . '>',
     );

     $status = wp_mail( $para, $assunto, $conteudo, $headers );

     if ( $status ) {
       echo "";
      } else {
        echo "erro";
      }
    }
  } );

 function FormularioCotacao_addJS() {
   $FormularioCotacaoURL = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/' . plugin_basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/';
   wp_register_script( 'processa', $FormularioCotacaoURL . 'js/processa.js' );
   wp_register_style( 'estilo', $FormularioCotacaoURL . 'css/estilo.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'estilo', $FormularioCotacaoURL . 'css/estilo.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'processa', $FormularioCotacaoURL . 'js/processa.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.12, true);
   wp_localize_script('processa', 'UrlCotacao', array('pluginsUrl' => plugins_url(), ) );
  }

  add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'FormularioCotacao_addJS');
```

By clicking "Make your simulation", `addCustomer()` is performed normally and writes the data in the database. I have a script that hides this form and displays another form (code below). This form should be sent by `wp_mail()`. But it does not work.

```
<div class='principal-form' id='principal-form2'>
    <form type='post' action='' id='cadastraForm2'>
    <input type='hidden' name='nome' id='nome' value='" + nome +"' />
    <input type='hidden' name='email' id='email' value='" + email +"' />
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='deliver_mail' />
</div>
<div class='col-md-35 padding-top-15'>
    <div class='texto-ola'>
        <p>Olá <span class='cor-vermelho'>" + nome + "</span>,</p>     <p>Estaremos enviando em breve sua cotação para o email <span class='cor-vermelho'>" + email + " </span>. Caso não encontre em sua caixa de entrada verifique nas pastas *SPAM* ou *Lixo eletrônico*, as vezes são redirecionadas para essas pastas!<br><br>É importante informar a profissão, pois podemos conseguir descontos maiores para determinadas profissões.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-65 padding-top-15'>
    <div class='texto-preencha'>
        <p class='font-uppercase'>Preencha os campos abaixo e receba uma comparação de todos os planos em seu email.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class='col-md-100'>
        <div class='titulo-form-p2'>Deseja Comparar: </div>
        <div class='col-md-30-2'><label><input type='radio' name='comparar' value='Planos de Saúde' id='comparar_0'> Planos de Saúde</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-30-2'><label><input type='radio' name='comparar' value='Planos Odontológiocs' id='comparar_1'> Planos Odontológicos</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can not make wp-mail function to work](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241203/i-can-not-make-wp-mail-function-to-work)

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/241203/94267

Comment: If you do not know to help, not hinder.

Comment: When I helped on the previous question you changed the question after. This question still has the bug that I did point out on the previous question.

Comment: If you'd like to start from scratch then at least please delete the older question to keep the site tidy.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to perform your wp_mail in the add_customer() to see if mails are sending.

Comment: @Benoti Perform  wp_mail in the add_customer() the email is sent. But this function is the first form. I want wp_mail function is executed in the second form (HTML placed separately).